# how to deploy java web app in windows azure

Tags: azure, cloud, jboss7.x, azure-storage, paas

I need to deploy my web application in Azure with JBoss 7 in PaaS mode.
I am able to run the app successfully in IaaS mode with windows virtual machine. But I need to run it in PaaS mode. 
Also, please let me know how to do the auto-scaling part in PaaS and what are the configurations or things I need to know before deployment.

Thanks in advance,
Anshu

Comment: Deploying Java in PaaS, and autoscaling, are two completely different questions. I suggest editing your question to remove the autoscaling part, and ask a separate question about that (you may want to peruse existing questions first, as this may have been covered already).

Answer (score 1):

To get started, look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690944%28VS.103%29.aspx) tutorial. This shows how to build and deploy a Java app from Eclipse, using the Windows Azure Plugin for Eclipse. This will build your deployment package and optionally upload it to Azure (and also let you test with the emulator).

When deploying to PaaS (worker role), the important thing is that you'll need a Java runtime as well as an http server (e.g. Jetty or Tomcat). You need to provide both of these. Now, If these become part of your deployment package, that package becomes unwieldy in size (I think it's around 50MB just for Tomcat+JVM). It's much better to store both of those in blob storage and, during role instance startup, copy them down to the local VM instance. Fortunately, the newest version of the plugin takes care of this for you. The tutorial I referenced shows exactly how this is done (basically a checkbox saying that you want to copy  the JVM and/or server to blob storage - nice and easy).

Once you get past the basics, you should look into using Maven.